# Sublime text find in selection

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

When I select multiple lines of text in text editor Sublime Text 3, and try to find (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) an existing string in it, it fails. In fact, any highlighting I do somehow makes the string unfindable. For example, if I highlight all text in my file, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> an existing string, it is unable to find any matches. Only when the string I want to find is not highlighted can the string be searched.

I have the 'in selection', 'highlight matches', and 'wrap' flags on when highlighting. My user preferences are as follows:

```
{
    "color_scheme": "Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Monokai.tmTheme",
    "font_size": 10,
    "auto_find_in_selection": true,
    "trim_trailing_white_space_on_save": true,
    "ignored_packages":
    [
        "Vintage"
    ]
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. I have been trying to figure this out for an hour. Originally I had "auto_find_in_selection" set to false - I thought that was the culprit, but the problem persisted even after setting it to true.

Comment: Make sure you have regex turned off, case sensitivity turned to the correct setting, and make sure you have the "selected" button turned on when you do ctrl-f.

Comment: The selected button was turned on (I referred to it in the post as the "in selection" flag), and the regex button is turned off as well.

Comment: I googled around, and believe my problem may have something to do with this: http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7062 , thought there does not seem to be a solution provided in that post.

Comment: you should make the second answer from @savigo the correct one. It fixed my problem. Did you see his answer?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I had been fighting with this problem as well and for now (ST3 Build 3059) it still seems to be a bug. It seems like that the editor is not updating the selection for the search/replace bar while you have it open.

Here's a workaround:

1) Close the find/replace bar

2) Make your selection

3) Open search/replace bar and enter your search query

Hope this helps!

Comment: This works, although a bit annoying since the bar has to be closed each time. I hope they fix this bug soon.

Comment: I"m using Submlime Text 2 and I have to do "find all" to make this work.

Comment: I was just facing the same problem, but in my case, the issue was that I had the 'Whole word' flag turned on. As soon as I turned it off, all was write with the world.

Comment: 4) click "In Selection" in the find/replace bar

Answer (score 51):

go to `settings`-> `user` and add this line:

```
"find_selected_text": true
```

next time you select a text and press `cmd+'f'` it will be there as default search.

Comment: Personally prefer to have this of since ctrl+d will do this once search bar is open.

Comment: Do you know of  way to change this such that it will work when only a single line is selected? The change you suggested only works if multiple lines are selected.

Comment: Actually this line worked better for me `"auto_find_in_selection": true,`. However it works only for multiple lines, i believe.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work with single lines. I have 500 lines selected (split lines on every other row and I want to replace the spaces with underscores). There doesn't seem to be a good way to do this.